# Format only the selected block of code in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to format only a selected block of code. I could only either format the whole file or the whole project with IntelliJ. I use community edition 2017.2 on MacOS.

Answer (score 17):

**From the [IntelliJ IDEA Help (Reformat File Dialog)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-file-dialog.html):**

1. Highlight the block of code.
2. Open the `Reformat File` dialog:

   - Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
   - Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
3. Click the "Selected Text" radio button.
4. Click the "Run" button.

**It should look something like this:**

[image: Imagine of Reformat File dialog]

Comment: Just `Ctrl+Alt+L` also does the job without showing this dialog, as long as the relevant code is selected. [Intellij Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_code)

Comment: Just `Alt+Shift+L` in KDE layout

Answer (score 3):

Yes; simply highlight the block of code and format it, either through the keyboard or through the menu.  How it will be formatted, and what will be formatted, are driven solely by your formatting preferences.

Comment: Thanks! I was all this while only looking at the option given to me on right-clicking the selected code which does not have formatting option.

Answer (score 2):

Reformat a code fragment in a file﻿:

1. In the editor, select a code fragment you want to reformat.
2. From the main menu, select Code | Reformat Code or press `Ctrl+Alt+L`.

**Note.** If you don't select a code fragment, IntelliJ IDEA will reformat the whole file.